# Why am I getting a leading sing quote in this echo?

Tags: bash

I am trying to debug a bash shell script where I am trying to surround a string/variable with single quotes.  I am seeing the following results and am stumped on how to debug this. It obviously has something to do with the content of the variable.  I thought the variable may be an array hence some of the echo statements.  IN_JSON is being constructed via calls to "jq" to construct some JSON.

```
echo "IN_JSON = ${IN_JSON}"
echo "IN_JSON = ${IN_JSON[*]}"
echo "IN_JSON = '${IN_JSON[*]}'"
echo "IN_JSON = '" ${IN_JSON} "'"
echo "${#IN_JSON[@]}"
```

Output:

```
IN_JSON = {"name":"RX-CLAIM-FILLED"}
IN_JSON = {"name":"RX-CLAIM-FILLED"}
'N_JSON = '{"name":"RX-CLAIM-FILLED"}
 '_JSON = ' {"name":"RX-CLAIM-FILLED"}
1
```

What's going on here and how do I troubleshoot this? It obviously has something to do with the contents of IN_JSON, but I'm not sure why or what is going on here.

Comment: This is a way to reveal the contents of a variable, including "control" characters: `printf "%s" "$variable" | od -c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expansion of `${IN_JSON[*]}` contains a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character that resets the position of the cursor to beginning of the line, so that the next character `'` is printed on beginning of the line.

Most probably, you want to run your file via `dos2unix`.

Comment: Also interesting, if IN_JSON is an array `${IN_JSON}` is equivalent to `${IN_JSON[0]}`, and if IN_JSON is a plain "scalar" variable, then using `[@]` or `[*]` is not an error and gives the same result as plain `$IN_JSON`